# Unexpected Response when using Spotify Web API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, spotify, node-modules, axios

I am following the implicit grant flow model as outlined in the Spotify Web Api tutorial [here](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/#implicit-grant-flow). 
However, rather than being prompted to login to Spotify as expected I am receiving an object in response. My get request seems to be correct since when I paste it directly into the browser I am prompted to login as expected:

My get request using Axios http request library:

```
axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url
})
.then(function (response) {
    console.log('RESPONSE', response)
})
.catch (function (error) {
    console.log('ERROR', error)
})
```

And the response object that is being returned:

```js
Object {
  client: Object,
  country: "US",
  locales: Array(2),
  BON: Array(3)
}
BON
  :
  Array(3)
client
  :
  Object
name
  :
  "MusicMaster"
__proto__
  :
  Object
country
  :
  "US"
locales
  :
  Array(2)
__proto__
  :
  Object
```

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're not supposed to do a GET request with axios here, you'll need to redirect (as it states in the first sentence of the documentation).

Comment: How would you redirect without using a GET request (as 2nd line of documentation suggests)? Thanks

Comment: With `window.open` for example.